# Run Tensorflow 2 prediction on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, aws-lambda

I want to run a Tensorflow 2 LinearClassifier on AWS Lambda. I have a trained LinearClassifier  tensorflow model. I want to run only the prediction in AWS Lambda, because of cost efficeny.

Currently I'm not sure how to handle it.

- I tried to use normal TF2, but it is too big for AWS Lambda Layers. All descriptions you find are with 
  older TF 1.1x versions and Python 2.x.
- Then I tried TensorflowJS, but it looks like the LinearClassifier using functions which are not implemented in TFJS.
- Last I tried to user Tensorflow Lite, but there I currently have problems to convert my model to TFLite.

**Do you have an idea, how I can get TF 2 Estimation of LinearClassifier running on AWS Lambda?**

Normally I think not all of the 1.5 GB Tensorflow modules are used for the simple prediction of an existing model. So is there a possibility to only get the files which are used for running the script?

Comment: have you found a solution here?

Comment: @MpizosDimitris I think I found a solution. I currently try to test them. You are now able to run own docker images up to 10GB Size as lambda function. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-image.html

Answer (score 1):

I have found possible answers for your question :

1. To transform in TFlite model :

- a blog about "How to convert a Tensorflow Estimator to Tensorflow Lite" : https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/how-to-convert-a-tensorflow-estimator-to-tensorflow-lite-a3509a9ba902
- an other example with Keras model but maybe the same trick with get_concrete_function (it works for me with my keras model): https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/experimental_new_converter/Keras_LSTM_fusion_Codelab.ipynb

2. To use with AWS Lambda, there are a lot of blogs but none of them is perfect. For my case, I used tensorflow 2.3.0 to create my keras model. So I have to modified a little this very good tutorial :

- https://www.edeltech.ch/tensorflow/machine-learning/serverless/2020/07/11/how-to-deploy-a-tensorflow-lite-model-on-aws-lambda.html or his github : https://github.com/edeltech/tensorflow-lite-on-aws-lambda

For the part : "Clone TensorFlow from the official GitHub repository", we need to force a version of tensorflow because sometimes latest version is not compiling well.

For my case, I want tensorflow v2.3.0, so i modified this line :

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
```

by

```
git clone --branch v.2.3.0 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
```

I have modified also at the end, to invoke lambda on AWS :

```
sls invoke local -f predict
```

by

```
sls invoke -f predict
```

I recommend you to do all the tutorial with the sample model provided to be sure everything is working.